# Why does Spring initialize the instances as singletons? What are some reasons that influenced their decision to handle initialization this way?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-roo

I don't understand the decision for why the Spring Framework is designed by default to return instances that are a singleton. So the same object is passed around when calling the application context. What are some reasons that influenced spring's decision to handle bean initialization this way? What are some bad things that can happen if all beans were initialized as prototypes?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think that Spring documents explain this point very well. Shortly the reason is that if your bean is stateless your do not need more than one instance. Since most beans are stateless "singleton" is a default scope. You can however change this. There are other scopes, e.g. session, request etc.

If for example you implement web store and need curt implementation session scope is what you need. If however you support special parameters that are sent for each request separately you probably want to use request scope for this purpose.

But beans that access database, perform authentication, send email or SMS, do other business logic can and should be implemented using singleton scope.

Comment: Basically the part that I don't understand is more of a rookie question. Why must beans that handle business logic should be implemented using singleton scope?

Comment: They don't *need* to be.  But after years of experience, many developers find that working with stateless objects which perform business logic leads to fewer issues with code.  (Easier to refactor, easier to make concurrent, easier to test,...)

Comment: could you please provide an example of a stateless business object that would be far more useful as a singleton than a new instance everytime